# How to get paired device info on Android Wear 2.0

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm developing an app for Android Wear 2.0. Is it possible to know if my wear is paired with an Android device or iPhone?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using the [PlayStoreAvailability](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/wearable/playstore/PlayStoreAvailability.html) we may assume that the paired device is an iPhone if the result is `PLAY_STORE_ON_PHONE_UNAVAILABLE`

UPDATE: Use [android.support.wearable.phone.PhoneDeviceType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/phone/PhoneDeviceType)